# Analytics User-ID view not tracking events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've created a new view in Google Analytics with everything set up the same as a currently functioning one, only with the addition of User ID tracking turned **ON**. It's using the same property so the UA code has not changed.

I've copied over everything that I can think of from the current view to the new view. At first glance everything was working fine, page views were coming through via Real-Time correctly and matched up with the values seen in the current view.

For some reason though, the new view is not listing **ANY** actual events in Real-Time, however the events graph is being populated.

[image]

The current view **IS** tracking all the events correctly.

We use Tag Manager to handle all our events among other things, and using the debug mode, all events were also being triggered correctly. Finally, I've also used the GA Debugger chrome extension, which again is not showing any issues. The new User ID property is being passed through to analytics as I'd expect.

I've tried searching for any issues related to User ID views and tracking events, but came up blank, presumably because there is no inherent issue with this set up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the reason that the events were not tracking is because **the user id was not being sent along with every event**.

I believed that once it was set on page load every analytics interaction after that would use that user id. This was not the case. **In Tag manager I added a 'Field to set' property for all relevant tags like so;**

[image]